# Getting index from entire table not just page in an angular mat-table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a mat-table with paging at 5 rows/page and when I click on a column link in a row, I'd like to get the row selected from the entire table index, not just the page I'm on.

ex. If I'm on the 3rd page and select the 3rd row I get an index of 3, not 18. I want 18.

I'm pulling the index like this from a link on a row column.
ex. of the column that calls a method and passes in the index

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="action" stickyEnd>
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index"> <span (click)="editSomething(i)">Edit</span> </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: The [paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#directives) exposes an [`PageEvent`](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#PageEvent). `pageIndex * pageSize + i` might give you the actual index in the whole table.

Comment: can I get these properties without an event? ex. through properties of the paginator class?

Answer (score 0):

```
  editSomething(element) {
      this.obj = this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.filteredData,this.dataSource.sort).findIndex( obj => obj === element);
  }
```

But to be honest, I think it's better to use an id on the element instead of working on its index ...

Comment: This might not be true if the sorting on the table and `myDatatableRecords` are not the same.

Comment: If you are showing it in datatable you can access to it's records, just use the real dataset.

Comment: problem is these aren't coming from a db so I don't have any unique id on the row. I'm not sure if I should create one in JS? But the user will be adding, deleting and editing rows

Comment: I added a test() function on the click of progress column try it yourself: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgnwq5